# Can element inside both arraylist be added together?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, addition

is there anyway where i can add the element inside both List 19 and List 20 together?

i have both of the element in integer form and by using List.get i can get the number. but i have trouble adding them in together as they are from different list and different if/else statement. is there anyway that i could add them up without changing the algorithm here?

```
List11.add(driver
        .findElement(
                By.xpath("html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/span"))
        .getAttribute("class"));
if (List11.get(0).equals(List10.get(0))) {

    String c = "1";
    ArrayList<String> List19 = null;
    List19 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List19.add(c);

    System.out.println(List19.get(0));
    System.out.println("Access Right add + 1point");

} else {

    String c = "0";
    ArrayList<String> List19 = null;
    List19 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List19.add(c);

    System.out.println(List19.get(0));
    System.out.println("Access Right no point will be added");
}

List12 = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out
        .println("Edit profile: "
                + driver.findElement(
                        By.xpath("html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/span"))
                        .getAttribute("class"));
List12.add(driver
        .findElement(
                By.xpath("html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/span"))
        .getAttribute("class"));
if (List12.get(0).equals(List10.get(0))) {

    String d = "2";         
    ArrayList<String> List20 = null;
    List20 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List20.add(d);

    System.out.println(List20.get(0));
    System.out.println("Access Right add + 2point");
} else {

    String d = "0";
    ArrayList<String> List20 = null;
    List20 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List20.add(d);

    System.out.println(List20.get(0));
    System.out.println("Access Right no point will be added");
}
```

Comment: I smell an `XY problem`. Tell us the functionality you're trying to achieve, and how adding elements from different lists helps with that.

Comment: This also needs an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: as seen above, i have strings that contain different value. i wanted to add those value up but i am not able to call those array outside the if else statement. i have reedited that part and im able to call the array outside.

Comment: this will solve the problem right? adding value inside them up? correct me if im wrong       List27.add(List19.get(0));
    List27.add(List20.get(0));  int y;
    double sum = 0;
    for (y = 0; y < List27.size(); y++)
     sum += List27.get(y);
    System.out.println(sum);